# Why is message struct always empty in my C++ implementation of Listener

Tags: android, c++, qt, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on FCM in a Qt app for Android and iOS. I've implemented a ::firebase::messaging::Listener in C++ which should pick up the messages and feed the information through to the QML layer for display etc.
Using sample code, the Listener implementation is registering fine, and the Listener::OnTokenReceived implementation is getting a token which I can then send back to my server to use as a registrationid when sending messages.
The problem is that every time I send a message through FCM, either using the on-line message composer or using a curl request, the message structure that is received by the OnMessage implementation has no content.

Here is the implementation (note that `m_handler` is a singleton component that connects to the QML layer: `setNote()` stores the QString and emits a signal.)

```
void FBListener::OnMessage(const ::firebase::messaging::Message & message)
{
    QString msg;
    ::firebase::messaging::Notification * n = message.notification;
    if (n)
    {
        msg.append(n->title.c_str()).append("\n");
        msg.append(n->body.c_str()).append("\n");
    }
    else if (!message.data.empty())
    {
        for (const auto& field : message.data)
        {
             msg.append(field.first.c_str()).append(": ").append(field.second.c_str()).append("\n");
        }
    }
    m_handler->setNote(msg);
}
```

Here is a snapshot of the QtCreator debugging pane if a breakpoint is set on the first line of the above method and a message is sent through FCM.

[image: QtCreator debugging pane as OnMessage is called]

and here is an example of the message I'm sending through a curl request (in my case I have a PHP script doing this as part of the server backend) The message is being sent successfully.

```
{
    "registration_ids":[
         "dAabVuI7Yuo:APA91bFEKguIMhJi0InKhfby-uDLgnhM9__-b9AxOKMguMtoNQsGU3I3ro_9VROYNyr90o9yhC9YseyIwh33pSA6ZpssBgEh1XOFRAHPYaCO5rAvVPVss9rvL5T0ADqafsB0VNahAOwv"
    ],
    "notification":{
        "body":"This is a test message",
        "title":"test message",
        "icon":"notify"
    },
    "data":{
        "test":"This is a test",
        "number":1
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea about firebase, but the is a member `notification_opened`. Maybe you need to call an "open" method on the received message before you can retrieve it. Check the firebase documentation again.

Comment: @Felix - that member indicates that the notification was clicked on from the toolbar. There is no (documented) open method on a Messagae...